# IMarketBillingService.java is never created in gen folder of the application?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, aidl

I have been working on an android application in which I have to integrate In-app billing. I am following the procedure given on the following link but it is not paying off.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-permission

On this link there is a section named *Adding AIDL file to your project*, When I follow the steps given in the section, I do not find any " IMarketBillingService.java" file in the "gen" folder of the project. What can be the issue? Has anybody faced this issue..?
Any help is regarding the issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well nothing worked for me like Cleaning and rebuilding project time and again....However creating a new project from the existing project solved the issue. In the new project I was able to add aidl file and then a corresponding java file was created in the gen folder. It might not be the best solution butt only this is the only thing that worked for me after 2 to 3 days of searching and mindstorming, so if someone has a better solution please do share...:-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Move .aidl file from project's src folder into some temporary folder.
2. Clean & build the project (build can fail, its just important that you start it).
3. Move .aidl file back to its place.
4. Clean and build again. This time everything should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

right click on project-->select property-->select java compiler-->set compiler compliance level to 1.6 or more than that